# Is there limit on the number of pinned tiles?

Tags: tiles

I am customizing my home screen quite thoroughly and I have many pinned tiles on my home screen now. I am wondering if there is some limit on the number of pinned home-screen-tiles.

Comment: I have 165 or so tiles pinned in me home screen and it works fine...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a hard limit, and not a practical limit, right? I have yet to read or talk to anyone who has noticed a hard limit. That being said, I imagine there is one. The bigger question is what comes first, the hard limit or the practical one?

Can you honestly, truly use your phone with 50 live tiles? Do you really need every contact pinned? Every application?

So, I can't exactly answer your question other than speculating. Perhaps myself or someone else can get in touch with a developer on the Windows Phone team and get a more solid answer for you. In the mean time, if you run into this problem please share :)

**edit**
I [found an article](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Microsoft-Unlimited-Live-Tiles-in-WP7-Only-15-Third-Party-Apps-Use-Them-171516.shtml) that mentions there is an unlimited number of tiles you can pin, but I don't see a reference for it. This still leaves the practical limit though.

I just found [this guy](http://thommck.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/windows-phone-7-pin-to-start-app-limit/) who claims to have 75+ applications pinned.

**second edit**
I think I approached this answer semi-wrong. Although it seems like there isn't a hard limit (or one anyone has run into with over 100 tiles) there **is a limit on notifications**.  You can only have 15 3rd party applications that subscribe to notification. So you can pin many, many tiles, but only 15 of those will update, per-say.

If you want the full details on the "15 app limit" You can view the official blog post [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaimer/details-on-the-push-notification-app-limits). In short:

> - Yes, the limit is fifteen third party applications can be concurrently subscribed  to receive push notifications (whether that
>   is a live tile or toast).  Parsing it out, the applications that come
>   out of the box (like outlook, people hub, etc.) will not count towards
>   this limit.    So there is no limit on 15 live tiles.  You can have
>   20+ if you add it up (that is about 2.5 screens worth of tiles on star
>   menu)
> - An application is only counted if it has push notification or tiles push enabled and is subscribed to a channel.  If you install an
>   application but you do not enable push, it would not count towards the
>   limit.
> - You should not have to go uninstall an application in order to free a slot.  If an application is coded well, it should be prompting users
>   and giving them the option on whether they want to use push
>   notifications and/or live tiles (since there is potential bandwidth
>   charges from the operator when these are pushed).   if the user never
>   agrees or it unchecks the box to subscribe, the application should
>   free the channel; there fore uninstall should not be required.
> - Applications that use just scheduled tiles updates do not count towards the limit. If that is all you need be a good citizen and
> - If an application subscribes for tile updates, and is never pinned it unfortunately does count. Again, we count the channels.
>
> Why is there a limit?  The usual thrive to ensure there is a great
> user experience, good battery life, quality of service on back-end and
> front-end, bandwidth (cost) , etc.  Limit will increase as we get
> right data on how people use push, impact, etc.  Kevin’s feedback on
> there not being an API to enumerate all push apps is still valid.  I
> know the product team has heard it (from Kevin, me and others) so I
> hope that gets addressed or the limits go high enough that the problem
> becomes a moot point.

Comment: I thought I'll just try that, but that could take a very long time in the case it is unlimited... :D

Comment: I had about 70 pinned items. Is very boring indeed. I even had used an app that shows something like separator black headers. Now a days I have about 50 tiles. And if I remove one I miss it.

Comment: If the theoretical number of tiles that can be pinned is unlimited (as the answer and article implies), then I suppose the actual practical limit (aside from usability) is whatever your memory will allow.

Comment: I just tried 101 tiles on 60 lines and it works smoothly.

Comment: @Victor I am also using grouping by black header tiles and I use about 40-50 tiles. The reason is probably that the app list is much worse than many tiles...

Comment: @Joe your second edit is interesting. Can you share the source for that information? Does that mean there can't be more than 15 notification-aware-apps OR only (first) 15 of them will be allowed to update?

Comment: I'll grab the source when I'm off my phone, but only 15 3rd party apps can have notifications. The 16th+ are not allowed. You have to disable one to add a new. you can have the other apps,the notifications just won't work

Comment: @jumbo source added

Comment: That's very thorough analysis of the topic! Good work, Joe!

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken I think Ben Riga (Tech evangalist, Microsoft) said that the maximum number of pinned tiles is 256 (2^8).

Which is almost unlimited :P

Comment: It would be nice to have the source of that info ;) And although it is true that 256 ia almost unlimited, it is also quite testable :D Maybe I'll try that...

Comment: @jumbo I'll ask him if he can confirm it! :)

Comment: Wow. A lot lower than I was expecting.